# Variable structure visibility in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, variables

I've create a structure in my program like this:

```
Public Structure Team_Data
    Public Shared punti_home As Integer
    Dim punti_away As Integer
    Dim goal_fatti As Integer
    Dim goal_subiti As Integer
End Structure
```

I use the variable of this structure in a Width for valorize it after a regex parser control, and I don't encounter problems. But if I would use the structure variable in a function like a parameter, so:

```
pressure(punti_home)
```

The compiler tells me that the variables isn't declared. Why happean this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to refer to it as `Team_Data.punti_home`.

Comment: Only question, if I add: forma_goal15(Team_Data.goal_fatti, Team_Data.goal_subiti), the compiler tell me: "the reference to a member don't shared require a reference to an object"

Comment: @AntonEgo

Shared variables are shared across all instances of a Structure/Class.  Non-Shared ones need an instance in order to access the data.  

eg. 
`Structure Animal
       Public Shared NormalNumberOfLegs As Integer
       Public AnimalTypeName as String
   End Structure

   Animal.NormalNumberOfLegs = 4
   Dim bob as New Animal
   bob.AnimalTypeName="cat"
   Dim fred as New Animal
   fred.AnimalTypeName="dog"`
bob.AnimalTypeName contains "cat", fred.AnimalTypeName contains "dog" - separate instances contain different data.  Access NormalNumberOfLegs from Animal/bob/fred is the same